# Getting a bus error trying to switch letters in a string

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, string-literals, bus-error

Below is a snippet of my code. My code is supposed to reverse alphabet chars only and skip any special characters. I am currently trying to use "ab-cd" and hope to print "ba-cd", but when I run my code I get a bus error.

I have narrowed down the issue to lines 31 and 32. I malloc'd, but unsure why it will not let me switch chars.

Although it does not show, I will make sure to free the memory using `free`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cytype.h> // used for isalpha()

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // declaring a pointer of type char to tempString
    char * tempString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* 6);
    tempString = "ab-cd";

    char temp;
    temp = tempString[0];
    tempString[0] = tempString[1];
    tempString[1] = temp;

    printf("%s\n", tempString);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tempString` points to a string literal. String literals are constants and cannot be changed. As a side note, the call to `malloc` is unnecessary and leads to a memory leak.

Comment: Please post all code as text, not a picture of text.

Comment: `tempString = "ab-cd";` discards the pointer you got from `malloc`, and replaces it with a pointer to a string literal which isn't writable.  You could copy the string `"ab-cd"` into the malloced space, if you allocated enough (currently you have allocated only enough for 1 character, and you need 6).

Comment: The `malloc` isn't necessary.  `char tempString[] = "ab-cd";` suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `tempString = "ab-cd";` is not doing what you think it is.  Just one line earlier you had stored in `tempString` the address of an allocated buffer.  In this line, however, you store the address of `"ab-cd"` in `tempString`.  You're not writing to the buffer but rather causing `tempString` to point somewhere else entirely.

Specifically, you're directing it a string literal which is stored in a read-only section of memory.  Therefore, trying to alter it as you're doing is going to crash your program.

What you want is to write the string **into** the buffer you already have.  This can be done by

```
strcpy(tempString, "ab-cd");
```

EDIT (thanks to @NateEldredge for catching this):

Your allocated buffer is not big enough to hold `"ab-cd"`.  You need to change the size of the allocation:

```
tempString = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
```

Comment: You'd also need to increase the size of the malloc'ed buffer to at least 6.

Comment: Yeah I was missing the * 6 in my malloc. Thank you. Also , your suggestions helped. I forgot that the way I was attributing tempString was making it a string literal. I used strcpy and saw the difference. Thank you for the help. It is greatly appreciated. Wishing good karma your way.

Comment: Code like `... malloc(sizeof(char)*6)` is a very bad idea, sorry no upvote from me.

Comment: I will endeavor to console myself.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you allocated not enough memory to store the string `"ab-cd"`

```
char * tempString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You allocated only one byte that can store only one character.

Then in the following statement you reassigned the pointer `tempString` with the address of the first character of the string literal `"ab-cd"`.

```
tempString = "ab-cd";
```

As a result the program produces a memory leak because the address of the allocated memory is lost.

Then you are trying to change the string literal pointed now by the pointer `tempString`. But any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

There is no need to allocate memory dynamically. You could just declare a character array and initialize it with the string literal like for example

```
char tempString[] = "ab-cd";
```

If you want to allocate an array dynamically you need to write

```
char *tempString = malloc( sizeof( "ab-cd" ) );
strcpy( tempString, "ab-cd" );
```

and then when the array will not be needed any more you should free it like

```
free( tempString );
```

Comment: thanks! This explanation really helped!

Comment: Having the hardcoded string `"ab-cd"` looks like a bad idea to me.